# URL Wildcard Redirect via htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

How can I wildcard redirect urls that share the same url ending?  I know if it's www.domain.com/page1/* you can redirect them all this way to a new destination url.   However, what if I need to only redirect if it matches the ending of the url string only.

For example, how do I redirect all urls that have the word post_ad.html at the end of them?

So that www.domain.com/page1/feb/post_ad.html  (all of these with post_ad.html at the end only) redirects to just wwww.domain.com/postnew.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (^|/)post_ad\.html$ /postnew.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: @ScottRogers then you should click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as the correct answer. ;) (You get bonus rep for doing so!)

Comment: Good to know it worked, can you now click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as the "accepted" one.